# Angular UI Router: state transition parent-child

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parent-child, angular-ui-router

```
.state('add', {
    parent: 'home',
    url:    'add/',
    views:  {
        'pop':  {
            templateUrl:    '/views/nav.html'
        }
    },
});
```

Transition from parent state 'home' to 'home.add' won't load template '/views/nav.html' into target view ('pop').

Everything else works just fine. The problem seems to be exclusive with child states.

I already tried like this:

```
.state('home.add', {
    url:    'add/',
    views:  {
        'pop':  {
            templateUrl:    '/views/nav.html'
        }
    },
});
```

Doesn't work as well. (I changed ui-sref="add" to ui-sref="home.add" in this case).

Both examples change the URL to the state URL, but doesn't seem to transition between states nor renders any views from the new state (if it has a parent).

Thank you.

@citizenslave fixed my problem, thanks!

```
.state('add', {
    parent: 'home',
    url:    'add/',
    views:  {
        'pop@':  {
            templateUrl:    '/views/nav.html'
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: Does your template from the `home` state have a `ui-view='pop'` to insert child state templates into?  If not, and you're using the `home` state's `'pop'` view, you have to address it in the appropriate state.  You can reference it absolutely with `'pop@home'`.

[UI-Router Wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)

Comment: @citizenslave Thanks, man! referencing the view 'pop@' did it! Thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template from the home state needs to have a `ui-view='pop'` to insert child state templates into. If not, and you're using the home state's `'pop'` view, you have to address it in the appropriate state. You can reference it absolutely with `'pop@home'`. [UI-Router Wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)